# Duplicate queries even if relationships are eager loaded

Tags: php, laravel

I am fetching a collection of invoices like below in a Laravel Command class:

```php
$invoices = Invoice::query()
    ->with('lease.activeTenant')
    ->whereOverdue()
    ->whereDate('payment_due_date', Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(5))
    ->get();
```

As you can see, I eager load the relationships: `lease` and `lease->activeTenant`.

For each invoice, I want to trigger a job that creates a PDF file and after that send out a notification to the tenant:

```php
$invoices->each(function (Invoice $invoice){
    Bus::batch([
        new GenerateClaimLetter($invoice),
    ])->finally(function (Batch $batch) use($invoice) {
        $invoice->lease->activeTenant->notify(new InvoiceClaimNotification($invoice));
    })->dispatch();

});
```

The above code executes 41 queries in total - 28 of these are duplicates. The duplicates are:

```sql
select * from `tenants` where `state` = 'active' and `tenants`.`lease_id` in (1)    
select * from `leases` where `leases`.`id` in (1)
select * from `invoices` where `invoices`.`id` = 1 limit 1
```

These queries get executed multiple times - probably due to that I am accessing the relationships inside the job `GenerateClainLetter` and in the notification `InvoiceClaimNotification`. Example:

```php
//GenerateClaimLetter.php

public function __construct(protected Invoice $invoice){}

public function handle()
{
    $lease = $this->invoice->lease;

    $content = view('layouts.claim-letter', [
        'invoice' => $this->invoice,
        'lease' => $lease,
        'tenant' => $lease->activeTenant,
    ])->render();

//...

}
```

I don't quite understand why so many duplicate queries are generated. The above is only if there is *one* invoice in the system!

Can anybody help me out in terms of reducing the number of duplicate queries?

Comment: try to add `exit;` before `$invoices` var and then after, just to see if it already makes those queries. please also share `layouts.claim-letter` view

Answer (score 0):

Try updating

> with('lease.activeTenant')

To

> with(['lease','lease.activeTenant'])